# Referencing instance method requires equivalency (SWIFT)

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I am trying to leverage SwiftUI and Combine to store user defaults for my application. Looking at suggestions in a few other posts, I have updated my code as you see below.  However, I am now getting the error of "Referencing instance method 'send()' on 'Subject' requires the types 'Setup' and 'Void' be equivalent".  It has been suggested that I change "Setup" to void in the PassthroughSubject, however this then gives a hard crash in the app at startup - " Fatal error: No observable object of type Setup.Type found."

I am at a bit of loss... any pointers would be welcomed.

```
    ==============  DataStoreClass ============

import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import Combine

class Setup: ObservableObject {

    private var notificationSubscription: AnyCancellable?

    let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Setup,Never>()

    @UserDefault(key: "keyValueBool", defaultValue: false)
    var somevalueBool: Bool {
        didSet{
            objectWillChange.send()  // <====== Referencing instance method 'send()' on 'Subject' requires the types 'Setup' and 'Void' be equivalent
        }
    }
    init() {

        notificationSubscription = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UserDefaults.didChangeNotification).sink { _ in
                   self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
}


============= property wrapper ===========
import Foundation

@propertyWrapper
struct UserDefault<T> {
    let key: String
    let defaultValue: T

    var wrappedValue: T {
        get {
            UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.my.app")!.value(forKey: key) as? T ?? defaultValue
        } set {
            UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.my.app")!.set(newValue, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not the best Combine coder, but by your definition of `<Setup,Never>` you are telling the compiler that in your `send` you will be passing a `Setup` instance, as in - I think - ``objectWillChange.send([insert your Setup instance here])`. I just don't see in your code exactly what this "Setup instance" is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that you have declared your `Output` type as `Setup`, but you are calling objectWillChange with `Void`.

So you have to pass self to objectWillChange:

```
self.objectWillChange.send(self)
```

Important thing to notice is that you should call `objectWillChange` not in `didSet` but in `willSet`:

```
var somevalueBool: Bool {
    willSet{
        objectWillChange.send(self
    }
}
```

You never set somevalueBool, so this bit of code will not get called anyway.

Your setup should look roughly like this:

```
class Setup: ObservableObject {

    private var notificationSubscription: AnyCancellable?

    public let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Setup,Never>()

    @UserDefault(key: "keyValueBool", defaultValue: false)
    var somevalueBool: Bool

    init() {
        notificationSubscription = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UserDefaults.didChangeNotification).sink { _ in
                   self.objectWillChange.send(self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to have fixed may major issues.. it is still not working like I think, as the SwiftUI code where I change the values doesn't seem to be "firing" the willSet() code.

Answer (score 0):

The `send` method requires you to pass the input type of the subject, or a failure completion. So your `send` lines should pass the `Setup`;

```
objectWillChange.send(self)
```

That said, in most SwiftUI code, `PassthroughSubject` is `<Void, Never>` (such that `send()` does not require a parameter). It's not clear what the source of the crash you're describing is; we would need to see the code that's involved in the crash to debug that. I haven't reproduced it so far.

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI doesn't use a `PassthroughSubject`, it uses an `ObservableObjectPublisher`. I am pretty sure that that is an alias for `PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>` but I'm not sure. The `ObservableObject` protocol defines a correct `objectWillChange` for you so the best thing you can do is to remove your definition.

The publisher is `objectWillChange` and as its name suggests it should be sent in `willSet` and not `didSet`, I don't suppose that it matters much but Apple changed from `didSet` to `willSet` and my guess is that they had a good reason.